# What am I doing wrong? Outputting the Variable name

Tags: matrix

[image: Im Trying to learn wolfram matrices but I got Stucked]

Im Trying to learn wolfram matrices but I got Stucked

Comment: `D` is a protected function.  Use a lower case variable name to avoid clashing with built-in functions (which always start with capital letters. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html

Comment: If you like to represent your matrices with capital letters, you can use script, gothic, or double-struck letters by typing `Esc scD Esc` for script, `goD` for gothic, or `dsD` for double-struck. As Chris mentioned, there are enough single-letter function names built-in that it's best to get used to avoiding them. Not all of them will cause problems right away, but `C, D, E, I, K, N,` and `O` are all used internally for various things. `D, E, I,` and `N` are functions and will always cause problems. Also, you can't directly use underscores in variable names.